# How do I call the different Amazon Regions in SP-API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

Do I need to change the endpoint of my call to get the Orders from Europe Region or only the Marketplace Ids?

I am 3rd Party developer and have plenty of successful integrations with North American Region and its Marketplaces.  I recently had a client who also uses Europe and Asia Region.
I am currently getting orders successfully in the North American region calling
https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com
Region: us-east-1

My application listing in Amazon has all the marketplaces checked off and All approvals are done.

For calling the European Region I switched the marketplaceids first but received no results (I changed the order statuses also).  I then changed the endpoint to the "https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com". But now I am getting an authentication error.

I double checked the Documentation for setting up the authentication at:
https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/authorizing-selling-partner-api-applications

> You must construct OAuth authorization URIs for the marketplaces in which selling partners will authorize your application. For example, if a seller has a Seller Central account for Mexico, they will need an OAuth authorization URI for Mexico (example: https://sellercentral.amazon.com.mx/apps/authorize/consent?application_id=amzn1.sellerapps.app.0bf296b5-36a6-4942-a13e-EXAMPLEfcd28) to initiate authorization of your application. Authorizations are regional. When the authorization is complete, your application will have access to the seller's account in any marketplace in the North America region. The same concepts apply to vendors using Vendor Central. You can use the GetMarketplaceParticipations API to discover the active marketplaces for a selling partner.

Do I need separate Authorizations tokens for Each Region a seller uses?
For example a client that sells in all 3 regions would have to do OAuth 3 times?
If I successfully support the America Region what would I change to support Europe and Asia?